# Regex to match Hebrew and English characters except numbers

Tags: regex, validation, hebrew

I have a question:
I want to do a validation for the first and the last name with RegEx.
I want to do it with only Hebrew and English without numbers.
Someone can help me to do that code?

Comment: This seems like a good place for this link: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Seemingly Hebrew has the range `\u0590-\u05fe` (according to [this nice JavaScript Unicode Regex generator`.](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/js/regex)

```
/^[a-z\u0590-\u05fe]+$/i
```

Comment: Should we throw a `$` in there as well for the end of the string?

Comment: Does it works with "change direction" unicodes? (RLM, LRM, `\u200f` `\u200e`). It could be a problem if the user changes from Hebrew to English and vice versa. My solution covers it https://stackoverflow.com/a/66104183/12695188

Comment: For .NET, one can use `\p{IsHebrew}` instead of `\u0590-\u05fe` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#supported-named-blocks)

Answer (score 9):

While the selected answer is correct about "Hebrew" the OP wanted to limit validation to only Hebrew and English letters. The Hebrew Unicode adds a lot of punctuation and symbols (as you can see in [the table here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_HTML_for_the_Hebrew_alphabet)) irrelevant for such validation. If you want only Hebrew letters (along with English letters) the regex would be:

```
/^[a-z\u05D0-\u05EA]+$/i
```

I would consider adding ' (single quote) as well, for foreign consonants that are missing in Hebrew (such as G in George and Ch in Charlie) make use of it along with a  letter:

```
/^[a-z\u05D0-\u05EA']+$/i
```

Answer (score 8):

### English & Hebrew FULL regex

I'm using the above regex on my application. My users are just fine with it:

```
RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z\u0590-\u05FF\u200f\u200e ]+$');
```

### The regex supports:

- English letters (includes Capital letters). `a-zA-Z`
- Hebrew (includes special end-letters). `\u0590-\u05FF`
- change direction unicodes (RLM, LRM). `\u200f\u200e`
- White space.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Not sure if it will work. If not, these references should help.

```
[A-Za-z\u0590-\u05FF]*
```

[Hebrew Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0590.pdf)

[Unicode in Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html)

Comment: Watch out, this matches the empty string and doesn't signify the start(`^`) or end(`$`) of the string.

Comment: Also, instead of posting, "Not sure if it will work," just pop on JSFiddle/RegExPal to try it out. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hebrew letters only:

```
/^[\u0590-\u05ea]+$/i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `\p{Hebrew}` in your regex to detect any Hebrew unicode characters (if you're regex engine supports it).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the RegEx pattern is between two `/`'s. The `i` at the end is a flag that says to be indifferent to the cases. `^` means the start of a line, and `$` means the end of a line. Brackets (`[` and `]`) means either of the characters inside the brackets. `-` means a range. Note that the characters are ordinal, so `a-z` or `א-ת` make sense; `a-z` means all letters from and include `a` to and include `z`. The same goes for `א-ת`. `+` means one or more of the preceding. So this pattern matches every sequence of letters from English or Hebrew.

P.S.: Also, note that the flavor of the RegEx is different in different languages and platforms. for example in `Sublime Text` the pattern would be: `(?i)^[א-תa-z]+$`.

```
/^[א-תa-z]+$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5
This work for me: Hebrew, English

```
NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[\\p{Hebrew} a-z]$",  options: .caseInsensitive).firstMatch(in: value, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: value.count))
```

Another languages you can get here - https://h2s1880.medium.com/how-to-use-regular-expressions-to-distinguish-national-languages-in-swift-c19d6d8d0a97