# How to completely separate word with non word with python? for Greek and Hebrew

Tags: python, findall

I want to separate all the words from non words in Greek and Hebrew.

I'm using this code:

```
words = re.findall(r'\w+|\S+', text)
```

the result is not so satisfying, for example:

- it separate ⸂ἡμῶν καὶ κυρίου⸃ -> (⸂ἡμῶν) (καὶ) (κυρίου) (⸃) which I want separated too (⸂) (ἡμῶν)
- it doesn't separate ⸂ὑπὲρ⸃ to (⸂)ὑπὲρ(⸃)
- it also doesn't separate [ὑμῖν] to ([) (ὑμῖν) (]) for Hebrew. It separate what is not suppose to be separated.

Comment: Hi OpenBiblica, have you looked at this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067355/regex-to-match-hebrew-and-english-characters-except-numbers

Comment: likely you need `re.UNICODE`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/393915/9214517

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the informations, I've found the solution with this for greek

words = re.findall(r'\w+|[[]⸂⸃()]|\S+', text)

but I still have problem with hebrew.
how to separate this 
עַל־ אֵ֣לֶּה׀ אֲנִ֣י 
to this ?
(עַל־) (אֵ֣לֶּה) (׀) (אֲנִ֣י)