# How to change a <input type="number"> to use a specific number format?

Tags: html, css, forms, localization, hebrew

According to the specification,

> This specification does not define what user interface user agents are to use; user agent vendors are encouraged to consider what would best serve their users' needs. For example, a user agent in Persian or Arabic markets might support Persian and Arabic numeric input (converting it to the format required for submission as described above). Similarly, a user agent designed for Romans might **display the value in Roman numerals rather than in decimal**; or (more realistically) a user agent designed for the French market might display the value with apostrophes between thousands and commas before the decimals, and allow the user to enter a value in that manner, internally converting it to the submission format described above.
>
> ([4.10.5.1.12 Number state (type=number)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#number-state-(type=number)))

Thus, I want to be able to tell the browser that I don't want the user to use a regular decimal numerical input, but rather that it should display a Hebrew (א, ב, ג, ...) numerical input. Is there some way to tell the browser to use Hebrew numbers, like one can for `<ol>` lists (the `type` HTML attribute and `list-style-type` CSS property)?

Is there some built in HTML/CSS property, and if not, is there some sort of ready-made plugin for this?

Comment: This is a bit uncharted territory to me, but I would imagine you could provide a regular `<input type="text">` with a `pattern` attribute that matches any of the characters in the Hebrew numbering system. Since I don't know how it works, I don't know if it has situations like Roman numerals where you can't have some characters next to each other. Maybe [this SO answer can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25067431/3624336), or [this article](https://jcuenod.github.io/bibletech/2017/08/19/matching-hebrew-unicode-regex/)?

Comment: @chriskirknielsen If I do that, then I will lose the up and down arrows, which is the whole point of the `type="number"` inputs.

Comment: This might not fall into your use case, but maybe [your shouldn't use `type="number"`](https://css-tricks.com/what-to-use-instead-of-number-inputs/). Then again, implementing the up/dowm arrow functionality in JS is a bit ludicrous… I won't be able to help you, I'm afraid, but I hope you find a solution, which looks like it might need to be a plugin indeed.