Regular expressions to match RTL+LTR strings
I've been given a document with some information written in Hebrew. I need to write regular expressions to extract structured data from the document with JavaScript (specifically Node.js). For example, if the document was in English and it contained the string

Date of birth: 10/04/2001

then I would write a regex such as /Date of birth: (\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})/ to extract the date of birth from the document.
However, since Hebrew is right-to-left but the numbers are left-to-right, it all gets mixed up.
Following the example above, when the document contains the string

תאריך לידה: 10/04/2001

the numbers are LTR and the label is RTL. How can I match that with a regular expression? It gets worse when I try to add code such as \d{2} to the regex after pasting the string in Hebrew. The code often ends up written backwards, mixed, sent to the beginning of the string, etc.
How is this done? I have zero experience with RTL languages.

Not an answer but this might help
This answer is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/25067431/7909604 because it provides this [\u0590-\u05fe]
When I copy your example into VS code I can simply do this: [\u0590-\u05fe\s]*:\s*\d{2}\/\d{2}/\d{4} and I capture תאריך לידה: 10/04/2001 in full.
In https://www.regextester.com/ I cannot match your text. I suspect there is a hidden character between the Hebrew and the colon, which VS Code is handling in a special way (because when I paste it in, the text switched to LTR).
I think to solve this, you would need to separate the issue of how text editors display the text and how the text is stored in fact.
